# Annotating a Generic Self return type?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I'm trying to make an "ORM" class in python, and I want to properly annotate the `id` field to be either an `int` if it was created by a query, or `None` if it was created by hand. This is to make it 'automatically' have the correct type of hint on `id` regardless of how the id field was made.

Here's how I'm trying to do it now:

```py
from typing import List
from typing_extensions import Generic, TypeVar, Self, TYPE_CHECKING
import pydantic

T_ID = TypeVar("T_ID")


class Entity(pydantic.BaseModel, Generic[T_ID]):
    id: T_ID

    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> Self[None]:
            ...

    @classmethod
    def find(cls: Self, filters: list) -> List[Self[int]]:
        ...

class ExampleSubType(Entity):
    pass

example1 = ExampleSubType(...) # Should be `ExampleSubType[None]`
example1.id # should be `None`

example2 = ExampleSubType.find(...) # should be `List[ExampleSubType[int]]`
example2.id # should be `int`
```

So here, the goal is that if you call `ExampleSubType()` Pylance knows that it's an `ExampleSubType[None]` and if you call `ExampleSubType.find()` it becomes `List[ExampleSubType[int]]`

But the `Self` type doesn't appear to carry across the `T_ID` generic information.

If I change to something like: `def find(cls: Self, filters: list) -> List["Entity"[int]]:`
the result is correct, but we lose `ExampleSubType` and it becomes just `List[Entity[int]]`

Is it possible to properly annotate a Generic Self, or is this pushing the limits of python's/pylance's typing system too far?

Edit: Reading [PEP-0673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes), this may not be possible.

> Note that we reject using Self with type arguments, such as Self[int]. This is because it creates ambiguity about the type of the self parameter and introduces unnecessary complexity: